# PYTHON; executing literal value of a variable

Tags: python

I have a lot of siltation in my understanding of python...having coded using a lot of other languages an Im a python noob so please forgive me for the obvious

My question is this;
I want to assign a string variable with an operator eg myop = "+"
Then use the actual value of the operator later in an expression eg (a myop b)
What is the best way to evaluate this?
I know there is eval for evaluating strings as an expression but I want to evaluate the actual operator here...

Thanks

Comment: You could turn the whole expression into a string first, given that your example, "+", needs two variables (or just one, if it's a number like +3). Then (safe) eval that string.

Comment: But, very likely, depending on your code and goal, there may be a much safer and/or easier way than evaluating a literal "+" string.

Comment: Note: for safe evaluations, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is probably your best choice.

Comment: You can't evaluate a single operator like '+', as it means nothing in isolation - it would just be invalid syntax. You might want to give us more details on what you are trying to achieve so that you can receive a more adequate answer.

Comment: Start by reading up on the `operator` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: @ThierryLathuille read question carefully. OP is going to use that operator in an expression.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for lightning response
Im doing remote scripting in Python for Ableton Live...so Im looking for simple, in GDL I would just bracket and do (a eval(myop) b) and it would eval the + and look for the LH and RH operands. Im doing parametric assessment first where a scrolling direction is ascertained and many call points then applied to a block of code. Eval() in python only seems to do a whole string...not good for this application. hth

Answer (score 1):

using **magic method** you can do something like this

```
OPERATORS = {"+": "add", "-": "sub", "*": "mul", "/": "div"}


def apply_operator(a, op, b):
    method = "__%s__" % OPERATORS[op]
    return getattr(b, method)(a)

a = "+"
print(apply_operator(1, a, 2))
```

but it only works while you are using **apply_operator**.
else you can't evaluate an operator like '+'. That would cause syntax error.